# Load JSON into backbone model

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I am trying to load a json file into a backbone model like so :

```
var Feed = Backbone.Model.extend();

var FeedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Feed,
    url:'feed.json'


var feeds = new FeedCollection();

feeds.fetch({success : function() {
       console.log(feeds);
}})
```

The first log returns the JSON obect within the file, just returns an object without the json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the `parse` function and not returning anything from it for the collection to add to itself. Removing `parse` from `FeedCollection` should allow it to populate.

Alternatively, return from that `parse` whatever properties you need from the server response to define your collection.

Comment: removed the parse and it's still not populating any models.

Comment: What does your model look like? What does the server JSON look like?

Comment: Yeah I think this is the issue, I thought if the model wasn't defined it would take the json's format?

Comment: I believe it should, if the server response is an array of JSON objects. If the server is providing something different, or the response is somehow nested, that may cause issues.

Comment: Yes, changed the json file to an array and it works.  How to I tell backbone which part of the json to populate the collection with?

Comment: Override the [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) function on the collection and have it return your set of models. Something like `parse: function(resp, opts) {return resp.collection;}`

Answer (score 0):

You should try and mention a few more properties for your fetch call. Try passing in the `method` argument and the `dataType` argument. If you are getting JSONP, try passing in `callback` too. Here is a code snippet I use that should help you out -

```
feeds.fetch({
    method:"GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback'
}).complete(function(resp) {
    // Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: No joy, I'm not using jsonp and adding the extra props/ complete function make no difference.